# Hotspot without AP in 14.04

Tags: hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I was following [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) guide to set up an hotspot on my Ubuntu 14.04, but suddenly I got this error

(32) Access Point (AP) mode is not supported by this device.

typing the line "iw list" in the terminal I discovered I haven't the "AP" connection available.
Almost every other how-to I found required it.

Now I'm asking you, there's a way for setting up my hotspot without getting a new wi-fi card, or buying something?